# How do I enable CORS in an online server using AJAX and PHP to get font for use on another BigCartel site

Tags: php, css, ajax, .htaccess, custom-font

I am currently using BigCartel to design a website.

I wish to use a custom font. No matter which server I use (currently a free Hostinger server) I cannot enable CORS using htaccess.

**Added to `.htaccess`:**

```
#   Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]]
```

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
font-family: FontName;
src: url(http://WEBSITE_URL.com/fontname.woff);
}
```

Comment: There's nothing related to CORS here as you are using the same origin.

Comment: You might need to check with Hostinger to allow `woff` files or you need to serve `woff` files using PHP.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I thought * acted as wildcard, not same origin? I am aiming for the origin to be http://www.murkyapparel.com (which masks murkyapparel.bigcartel.com).

I know the problem is not that I can't serve woff files, as using AngularJS shows an error with whichever directory I use.

Comment: Ah... Grr... That's bad.

Comment: @Praveen should I remove the rewrite rule?

Comment: I am not sure. Try removing it? With hostinger's free plan I had the same issue. Keep simple in that, as it doesn't support all the file types.

Comment: I read something saying that using *is depreciated and that specific URLs should be used, although I am unsure whether I should be writing the origin as murkyapparel.bigcartel.com or as murkyapparel.com

Comment: OK thanks I will look now

Comment: Sure buddy... Let's see. Keep us updated.

Comment: Still no luck. Im guessing my markup is OK as I pretty much copied it from the enable-cors website. I also tried using TTF and still no joy.

Comment: Man... Do this... Have a PHP file read that stuff, and then spit it with correct headers?

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go. Dunno how quickly I will update as I am still trying to get my head around PHP but I will share if I make progress. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Sure. All the best. For now I will add you an answer on how to do.

Comment: Excellent thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the free hosting will not provide support for all the files. But having PHP support is one of the great things. So what you can do is, use PHP to serve the files in the correct format.

So for your issue, if you have `font-name.woff`, which has `application/x-font-woff` as the MIME Type, what you can do is, create a proxy PHP script that does something like this:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  header("Content-type: application/x-font-woff");
  echo file_get_contents("file-name.woff");
?>
```

Make it generic and serve all the files this way:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  header("Content-type: application/x-font-woff");
  echo file_get_contents("{$_GET["file"]}.woff");
?>
```

And call it as: `font.php?file=file-name`. Hope this helps.

Additionally, to incorporate CORS into PHP file:

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  ob_start();
  header("Content-type: application/x-font-woff");
  echo file_get_contents("{$_GET["file"]}.woff");
?>
```

Comment: @DjDaihatsu Please do not use that script as is.  It is a HUGE security vulnerability to allow user input to be used directly in a file path like this.  Perhaps you need to validate that `$_GET['file']` matches one of however many expected values before you work with it, with any values not whiltelisted returning a 404 or similar.

Comment: @DjDaihatsu Agreed with the above comment. So, you need to make sure you give validation, by giving it only to the WOFF files.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I have very basic experience of PHP, which largely consists of copy and pasting.

However, the server which I am using isn't actually for anything more than storing fonts at the moment, so I presume that it would only pose a risk to my font files?

Comment: @DjDaihatsu Don't worry... Right now no issues for that, because it checks for only WOFF files. `:)` This is not a security issue, but this might be one, if you are gonna do it for everything, like say, `file_get_contents("{$_GET["file"]}");` Agreed?

Comment: OK yes that makes sense. Thanks again :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar You should never, ever, ever use user input without validating/sanitizing it. You could add a few extra "never ever's" for cases where you are then going to perform a file system operation with that input. What if the value passed via GET was something like `http://domain.com/path/to/exploit?a=`  That would render your `.woff` extension as nothing but a meaningless parameter and would potentially allow execution of a malicious remote file on your server.  So even though you think adding `.woff` looks safe, please understand that it is not.

Comment: @MikeBrant Sure buddy. Will do.

Comment: For full CORS support, we may have to add :  `header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");` `header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');`  `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept');`